# Google Visualization API google.charts.Bar(chartDiv) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I have a code that sends a get request to a data source via AJAX then draw a bar chart, like so:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["bar"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    $.get("/pop-pyramid", function(data) {
        var table = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

        var chart = google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("popPyramid"));
        console.log(chart);

        chart.draw(table, {stacked: true});
    }, "json");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button#downloadData').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.assign('/path/to/downloadable/file');
    });
});
```

This unfortunately throws

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined
    at Object.success (statistics.js:11)
    at i (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)
```

Comment: What does  console.log(chart); prints for you ?

Comment: @VinodLouis `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance:

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("popPyramid"));
```